# Why does my script still send the email even though conditions are not met?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am coding this on Google App script. Even though the conditions are not met on my google sheets, it still sends out the email. Appreciate any help

```
function CheckAgingProduct() {
// Fetch the Aging Product
 var CheckAgingProduct = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AGING REPORT").getRange("J2:J"); 
  var NumberofAgingProduct = CheckAgingProduct.getValue();

 // Check No. of Aging Product
  if (NumberofAgingProduct<0){
    return 
  } else {
      // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL LIST").getRange("A2:A");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = " Aging Product more than 120 Days!"; // Second column
var subject = 'Aging Product';

for (let i=0; i<emailAddress.length; i++) {
  if (emailAddress[i][0] === '') {
    return
  } else 
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail (emailAddress[i][0], subject, message)
    Logger.log('Sent email to ' + emailAddress[i][0])

     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call the `getValue` function

Comment: oh so sorry im new to this how do you call the getValue function? @ThumChoonTat

Comment: `CheckAgingProduct.getValue` should be `CheckAgingProduct.getValue()`

Comment: hm tried doing that but the code is still sending out email when there is no value in the range @ThumChoonTat

Comment: You need to provide more info. You've used Logger.log in your function. Can you provide what the Logger output is?

Comment: Hi the logger output shows whether the email has been sent. In this case, regardless of whether the condition is met, the logger appears every time meaning to say the code is sending out the email even though the condition is not met!  @AnsonYeung

Comment: Do let me know what other info might be helpful!! @AnsonYeung

Comment: It should output "Sent email to <something>" right? Does it actually output something or it output "Sent email to "

Comment: It would also be good to try `Logger.log(emailAddress)` to see what data is contained inside `emailAddress`

Answer (score 1):

You should correct `if( NumberofAgingProduct < 0 ) {...` to `if( NumberofAgingProduct < 1 ) {...` because the number of aging products cannot be less than zero.

Comment: Tried changing but it is still sending out the email when there is no data in the range

Comment: that's either because the condition was met or you have accidentally doubled the code in the document which overrides the one corrected.

Comment: Hm but this is the only code that I have in the document!!